# Change single variable of react state

Tags: javascript, html, css, design-patterns, reactjs

Is it allowed to assign a single variable of react component state like `this.state.foo = "bar"` without calling setState? I need to change part of the state in multiple places, and I'm unable to use object spread operator and Object.assign is too verbose. How to change just a part of the state without redefining the whole state?

Answer (score 10):

You should use `setState` rather than instance variables because it is important that React knows about state changes so that it can trigger renders appropriately.

Because of the diffing algorithm React uses on the DOM it is efficient to call `setState` as often as you like.

Note that calling `setState` on one variable will leave the others unchanged:

```
this.setState({ foo: 'bar' }); // Does not change foo2
```

Answer (score -2):

Just like that

```
this.setState({ foo: 'bar' )};
```

Comment: Your answer would benefit from some explanation but you're totally right, there's no need to create the whole new state object yourself.